# como mostrar u ocultar un input según la opción seleccionada en un input select?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

necesito que se muestre un input cuando selecciono la opción 2 en un selector, soy nuevo en vue y no se realmente como se hace.
No se si tengo que capturar el valor con un `onchange` ¿o hay otra manera de hacerlo?.

```
         <v-tab-item value="access">
                          <v-form ref="form">
                                <v-row style="margin-top: 20px;" >
                                    <v-col cols="12">                
                                        <v-select 
                                          v-model="data.accessType"
                                          :items="accessTypes"
                                          v-bind:value="accessTypes.id"
                                          item-text="name"
                                          item-value="id"
                                          menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                          :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.access-type_placeholder')"    
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col cols="12" v-if="accessTypes.id == 2">
                                          <v-select 
                                             chips
                                             multiple
                                             v-model="data.workplaces"
                                             :items="data.name"
                                             item-text="name"
                                             item-value="id"
                                             menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                             :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.workplaces')"
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col cols="12">
                                          <v-select
                                             chips
                                             multiple
                                             v-model="data.departments"
                                             :items="data.departments"
                                             item-text="name"
                                             item-value="id"
                                             menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                             :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.departments')"
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                       <v-col cols="12">
                                          <v-select
                                             chips
                                             multiple
                                             v-model="data.projects"
                                             :items="data.projects"
                                             item-text="name"
                                             item-value="id"
                                             menu-props="bottom, offsetY"
                                             :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.projects')"
                                          />
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col cols="12">                
                                          <v-text-field
                                              v-model="data.employees"
                                              :label="$t('wkt.admin.activity-types.edit-activity-types.access-type_employees')"
                                              autocomplete="none"
                                              :rules="[validationRules.required]"
                                              max="400"
                                          />
                                      </v-col>
                                </v-row>
                           </v-form>
                        </v-tab-item>

  data() {
      return {
         showDialog: false,
         loading: true,
         tab: 0,
         data: {},
       
         accessTypes: [{id:1, name:'Toda la empresa'},
                           {id:2, name:'Un grupo concreto'},
                           {id:3, name:'Equipos o proyectos'},
                           {id:4, name:'Trabajadores concretos'},
                            {id:5, name:'Script'}
                           ],
      }
   },
```